# How to change the tags url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the url from the wordpress tags like this

```
www.xxxxxx.com/?tag=chromatography
```

but I want like this

```
www.xxxxxx.com/?s=chromatography
```

Can anybody tell me how can i change the url setting which generate from the tag?

Any help is appreciable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a URL rewrite ([documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)), either in a local `.htaccess` file or your main Apache VirtualHost file (assuming you are using Apache).

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.+)
RewriteRule ^/?(index.php)?$ /?tag=%1 [R,L]
```

The above means that anyone visiting either **`http://yoursite.com/index.php?s=chromatography`** or **`http://yoursite.com/?s=chromatography`** will see that URL int he address bar, but Wordpress will understand it as meaning
**`http://yoursite.com/?tag=chromatography`**

So the tag behaviour will function as expected.

To change the URL which wordpress itself puts out for tags, you can apply a [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference), as mentioned in the documentation for [`get_tag_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tag_link).

For that, add something like the below to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function my_custom_tag_link($taglink, $tag_id) {
  return str_replace($taglink, '?tag=', '?s=');
}
add_filter('tag_link', 'my_custom_tag_link', 10, 2);
```

**N.B.** That PHP code is not tested, but as far as I can tell should do the trick.